# Exercising GM warrant

Tags: stocks, warrants

I have some GM WSA warrants and WSB warrants.  Can someone please explain how to exercise them?  I have read that they were issued with strike prices of around $10 on the WSA and $18 on the WSB, but I don't know if that means that that is what I would pay to exercise the warrants now (oct 2013).  My statements currently show WSA's at about $26 and B's at $18.  My ultimate goal is to get rid of all of it.  Do I have to exercise the warrants first to acquire GM stocks which I would then sell, or what?

I have searched the net high and low for an answer to this and have found nothing (except some interesting info on this site about cost basis for these warrants).  Would appreciate any info.

Answer (score 4):

No, if your aim is to simply get rid of your warrants, you do not have to exercise the warrants to acquire the stock and then sell the stock. You can sell the warrants directly on the secondary market.

You should be able to get information on warrants and how to exercise and trade them from your local stock exchange and the warrant issuer.

Comment: But if the warrants are currently priced at roughly 26 and 18, and the stock is currently 36, am I "leaving money on the table" by just selling the warrants at their current prices?

Comment: No, you are not leaving money on the table because you have to pay money to exercise the warrants to acquire the shares. You will find that the price of the warrants + their exercise price = slightly more than the share price (due to interest and financing costs).